# How do swf recorders work?

Tags: video, flash, avi, mpeg

There are some software to convert swf file into avi, mpeg or other types of video files. But how do they actually work?

Comment: They may use the BitmapData.draw(stage) at every frame, hold them in an array, loop the array and make an new Bitmap which they save?

Comment: but they are other applications, not as embedded in swf

Comment: Ah, read it in a hurry. Well that I do not know... SWF is an open specification so I think they just build their software around it. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf.html

Answer (score 2):

The SWF is played and a bitmap screengrab is made of the SWF on each frame. All of the screengrabs are then compiled into a video and compressed/exported in your desired format.